# Abbreviations used in Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, support

I see that many short forms of words are used in Stack Exchange such as VLQ, POB, VTC, etc. When I search for them in Google , VTC gives Vocational Training Council, Virtual Training Company, etc. VLQ stands for variable-length quality and POB gives Post-Office box, Place of birth, etc. I do not seem to understand the sentences used in Stack Exchange while applying the Google long forms of the word. Can anybody help me in understanding the meaning of these.

Comment: I hit the very same problem a couple of years later with VTC, and I have been on this list quite a while. The use of these acronyms is really bad imho — see comment on the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a **[StackExchange Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)** for the terms used In SE that differ from Google.

## Some of them are:

**VLQ** = Very Low Quality.

**VTC** = Vote To Close.

**POB** = Primarily opinion based.

**OP** = Original Poster.

**NAA** = Not an answer.

**CW** = Community Wiki.

**Rep Recalc** = Rechecking of rep by the system.

**Roomba** = Automatic [deletion of posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) by the Community User.

**Winter bash** = Celebrating the end of the year where users can win hats. [See Winter bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/)

**Sock puppet** = Duplicate account created by users to cast additional votes on their posts or any other activities.

**XY Problem** = When a user asks for a problem X, actually when they need to solve problem Y thinking they may get better response with X, when in reality it would have been much better for them to ask for problem Y.

**Spam Seed** = Questions which are liable to attract spam.

**SOFU** = Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault.

**Child-Meta** = Meta site attached to the main site.

**Burninate** = To delete tags.

**Dupehammer** = Privilege of gold tag badge users to close a post as duplicate, when the post has the specific tag initially introduced by the OP.

**SEDE** = [Stack Exchange Data Explorer.](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: TIL that "burninate" is an official SE term. Now my mind goes back fondly on the history of the interwebs...

Comment: Please avoid using these acronyms and terms. They are almost never necessary, they confuse those who are unfamiliar with them and give an impression of being the language of an elite inner group. This is one of the first rules of communication.