# Bannering the main site for coronavirus

Tags: discussion

The community mod Jnat offers assistance in case we wish to have a banner, for example one that links to a meta post that explains what to ask here on Bio, what not to ask, and to resources where to find information. Academia.SE has made a [meta post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/i-need-help-adapting-my-academic-teaching-to-the-covid-19-coronavirus-crisis-w) with a lot of info. We have a similar, yet less centralized [meta post here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses) that could be linked to.

- Anyone feels to have a banner during the corona surge on our site?
- Anyone feels to have a [new or updated] meta post detailing Bio-related information?

**EDIT**:
After waiting a while I haven't seen any further suggestions for a meta post, so I asked JNat to put up a banner with a link to the [meta post from David](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses#4035). Based on David's request I changed it to a community wiki post. I also took the liberty to remove the discussions in the comments, as they were nearly 4 weeks old.

Comment: What form would this banner take?

Comment: I think such a banner is a good idea, though I think the previous meta post you link to carries enough baggage, emotions, and history to warrant a new post that is more of a community wiki type of thing. (I say all this, though, without the personal time to invest much into it -- I'm a bit swamped atm converting all of my courses to online teaching with ~3 days notice from my institution!!)

Comment: @theforestecologist Maybe https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/i-need-help-adapting-my-academic-teaching-to-the-covid-19-coronavirus-crisis-w would be useful to you!

Comment: @canadianer I think it would be similar to the one on https://academia.stackexchange.com/ which links to a community wiki that includes some quick site FAQ for people that are new here plus a collection of related questions. But I would consider AliceD's post here to be a solicitation for suggestions as answers as to what the banner would say as well as what a linked meta post should include.

Comment: The Academia one is "If you need help with online teaching or other challenges in academia arising from the COVID-19 crisis, we have prepared this FAQ to get you started." because many people, like @theforestecologist , are suddenly needing to modify their courses and there has been a flood of Q&A there with lots of overlapping questions being asked by different people.

Comment: I'm sorry for the slow follow up, but life's a  big mess right now (2 small kids that need home-teaching, desperate students, frozen projects) -- you know the drill...). I'll do the best I can, but it will take a while.

Comment: @theforestecologist --  I haven't seen any suggestions, so perhaps a link to 'the' meta post would be the best option? Let me know.

Comment: @AliceD I reckon so, since that's at least some discussion and linked sources of info.

Comment: @AliceD What would you think of cleaning up the other answers there too? It seems like the main point is the one answer which has diverged a bit from the original question and other answers. Maybe it's better to move that content elsewhere? Sorry I haven't made any effort prior to this to help...

Comment: @BryanKrause - I'm afraid I don't fully understand your suggestion, but please feel free to do whatever you think is best! It's a community wiki now.

Comment: @AliceD I think you've already done much of what I had in mind. I made some edits to one of the remaining posts; I'd appreciate some peer review of my work and please add whatever else you think is useful.

Comment: @BryanKrause - all seems well imho !

Answer (score 3):

I feel strongly that any banner should be linked to the meta post, not the main site. Perhaps this is the time for that post to be taken out of my hands by the Community (however that works) and expanded by others. (I did ask for help expanding it but none was forthcoming. I have done what I can.)

Comment: You did well. I meant to have the banner on the main site and a link in it that directs to the / a meta post. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks again for all your efforts. The meta post did end up in some (over)heated debates, but in the end the meta post was necessary, very necessary. Cheers.

Comment: @AliceD — Thanks. The eventual outcome is gratifying to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have made edits to the linked question to generalize the post. I have also taken the liberty to edit the answers here and there, and I have removed many discussion-based contents. We have had enough time to sort things out internally, and the post is now aimed to new users, instead of a discussion hot spot for hi-repped Bio users.

I have also removed the comments and deleted some answers that were discussion answers only.

I hope that everyone can agree.

The post is community wiki now, and feel free to improve the post wherever needed.

Thank you for everyone's considerations and input, and a special thanks for David to initiate this effort.